# C: Moving free statements into separate function causes memory leak

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following structure and initialisation of it in a C file:

```
struct Lattice {
    int length;
    int** latt;
};

struct Lattice* Create(int size){
    struct Lattice latt;
    int i,j,k,l;

    latt.length = size;
    latt.latt = malloc(sizeof(int*) * latt.length);

    for(i=0; i<latt.length; i++){
        latt.latt[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * latt.length);
    }

        for(j=0; j<latt.length; j++){
            for(k=0; k<latt.length; k++){
                latt.latt[j][k] = 0;
            }
        }

    struct Lattice* lattp = &latt;
    return lattp;
```

And I also have the memory freeing function:

```
void Destroy(struct Lattice* lattp){
    int l;
    for (l=0; l<(lattp->length); l++){
        free(lattp->latt[l]);
    }
    free(lattp->latt);
}
```

But whenever I run the code:

```
int main(){
    struct Lattice* lattp = Create(5);
    Destroy(lattp);

    return 0;
}
```

I get a memory leak (according to Valgrind it is 40 bytes definitely lost and a further 80 indirectly lost, if this makes any difference).

But if I have identical code except that I write the free statements, which are identical to the ones in Destroy, into Create (and modify the return statements appropriately), I don't get a memory leak. Why does moving the free statements into a separate function cause a memory leak?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: That's because latt is a stack variable. You should not return the address of a stack variable from a function

Comment: Because your create function doesn't allocate the structure.

Comment: In addition to the local variable issue, you shouldn't allocate 2D arrays this way. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker My problem was that I didn't realise that I still have stuff in local scope (the length variable), so it isn't quite a duplicate I feel. Although for people not interested in this specific code it will probably be the same issue as the other post, not sure what the guidelines are for duplicated stuff in this case!

Comment: @DanielJ : me marking as duplicate does not mean you shouldn't have asked the question (you couldn't have known there was another question addressing the cause of your problem since you didn't know what the cause was). It's rather intended for future viewers of this question as you yourself indicated. Or to put it differently : in this case, the question isn't a duplicate, but the answer is.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but instead of looping through every element and zeroing them, you can just use `calloc` instead of `malloc` when allocating space.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Create()` function returns the address of a local variable:

```
struct Lattice* Create(int size){
    struct Lattice latt;  // this is a local variable - it only exists
                          // as long as the function Create() is running
    int i,j,k,l;

    latt.length = size;
    latt.latt = malloc(sizeof(int*) * latt.length);

    for(i=0; i<latt.length; i++){
        latt.latt[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * latt.length);
    }

        for(j=0; j<latt.length; j++){
            for(k=0; k<latt.length; k++){
                latt.latt[j][k] = 0;
            }
        }

    struct Lattice* lattp = &latt;  // this takes the address of a local variable
    return lattp; // after this return, latt no longer exists
}
```

This is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a).

Comment: Thanks! So would using malloc to assign memory for everything in the struct solve my issue?

Comment: @DanielJ You can either `malloc()` the structure and return a pointer to it, or you can return the structure itself.